# PHP if statement building URLs

Tags: php, if-statement

I have written the following IF statement

```
if ($mainCat && $subCat) {
    $url = "/subjects/".$mainCat->alias."/".$r->alias;
}
```

Which is working great. You can see a demo here: http://217.199.187.199/equityschooltravel.co.uk/

However I have expanded on it and want to include an elseif, if a variable is present but it's not working:

```
if ($subCat == 78) {
    $url = "/subjects/".$mainCat->alias."/".$subCat->alias."/".$r->alias;
}
elseif ($mainCat && $subCat) {
    $url = "/subjects/".$mainCat->alias."/".$r->alias;
}
```

The idea is, if a country ($subcat) is selected with an ID of '78' the URL will be rendered differently.

Comment: Can you please explain what does 'not working' mean? Do you get any errors? Is the result not expected?

Comment: Considered `isset();` or `empty();` although I might have misunderstood your question

Comment: this is obviously failing you `if ($subCat == 78)` since the first piece of code contains the same but set in your `elseif`

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: @Andrew I've just updated the question - thanks

Comment: you can also try using an `else` rather than `elseif` as in `else { $url = "/subjects/".$mainCat->alias."/".$r->alias; }`

Comment: @ me if you need me. Moving on... cheers

Comment: if $maincat == 78, you'll never enter in else if.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I fixed it by doing:

```
$diffCats = array('76','77','78','79','80');

if ($mainCat && $subCat) {
    $url = "/subjects/".$mainCat->alias."/".$r->alias;

    if (in_array($subCat->id, $diffCats)) {
        $url = "/subjects/".$mainCat->alias."/".$subCat->alias."-language-trips/".$r->alias;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

if $maincat == 78, you'll never enter in else if. check for not existing subcat in if and then if the subcat is set you'll go for the else if.

```
if ($main && !isset($subcat)) {
    $url = "/subjects/".$mainCat->alias."/".$r->alias;
}
elseif ($mainCat && $subCat) {
    $url = "/subjects/".$mainCat->alias"/".$subCat->alias."/".$r->alias;
}
else ....
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no error....

or may be i misunderstood your question:

```js
<?php

$url = "";

$subCat = 70; // 78

$mainCat = 1;

if ($mainCat && $subCat == 78) {
    $url = "subcat 78";
}
elseif ($mainCat && $subCat && $subCat != 78) {
    $url = "url other";
}

echo $url;

?>
```